# Angular 8 problem on showing list with api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem in angular 8 with printing my list in page 
here is my code proposal-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";
import { Proposal } from "./proposal";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { ProposalService } from "./proposal.service";

@Component({
  selector: "proposal-show",
  templateUrl: "proposal-show.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["proposal-show.component.css"],
  providers: [ProposalService]
})
export class ProposalShowComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private proposalService: ProposalService
  ) {}
  @Input()
  proposal: Proposal;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let proposalRequest = this.route.params.flatMap((params: Params) =>
      this.proposalService.getProposal(params["id"])
    );
    proposalRequest.subscribe(response => (this.proposal = response.json()));
  }
}
```

this is my proposal.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Proposal } from "./proposal";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { throwError } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { retry, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class ProposalService {
  private proposalsUrl = "http://localhost:3002/proposals";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getProposals(): Observable<Proposal[]> {
    return this.http.get<Proposal[]>(this.proposalsUrl).catch(this.handleError);
  }
  getProposal(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.proposalsUrl + "/" + id + ".json");
  }
  handleError(error) {
    let errorMessage = "";
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // client-side error
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // server-side error
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

this is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { HomepageComponent } from "./homepage/homepage.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { DocumentsComponent } from "./documents/documents.component";
import { DocumentService } from "./documents/document.service";
import { ProposalComponent } from "./proposal/proposal.component";
import { ProposalNewComponent } from "./proposal/proposal-new.component";
import { ProposalShowComponent } from "./proposal/proposal-show.component";
import { ProposalService } from "./proposal/proposal.service";

import {
  NgbPaginationModule,
  NgbAlertModule
} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomepageComponent,
    DocumentsComponent,
    ProposalComponent,
    ProposalNewComponent,
    ProposalShowComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgbPaginationModule,
    NgbAlertModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [DocumentService, ProposalService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

this is my show page

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngIf="proposal" class="card proposal-card">
    <h1>{{ proposal.customer }}</h1>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div>
        <p>Hi {{ proposal.customer }},</p>

        <p>
          It was a pleasure getting to meet with you and review your project
          requirements, I believe it is a great fit for the types of
          applications that I build out. Please feel free to check out some of
          my past projects
          <a href="{{ proposal.portfolio_url }}">here</a>.
        </p>

        <p>
          To successfully build out the application I will be utilizing
          {{ proposal.tools }}, and a number of other tools to ensure that the
          project follows industry wide best practices.
        </p>

        <p>
          Ensuring that you are fully informed is one of my top priorities, so
          in addition to incorporating everything that we discussed, I will also
          be creating a project management dashboard and sending you a project
          update message daily so that you can have a transparent view of the
          development as it takes place.
        </p>

        <p>
          To accomplish the project and meet the requirements that we discussed,
          I am estimating that it will take
          {{ proposal.estimated_hours }} hours in development time to complete.
          The project should take {{ proposal.weeks_to_complete }} weeks to
          complete and with my hourly rate of {{ proposal.hourly_rate }}/hour,
          the estimated total will be
          {{
            proposal.hourly_rate * proposal.estimated_hours
              | currency: "USD":true:".0"
          }}.
        </p>

        <p>
          The next step from here is to set up a meeting to finalize the project
          and sign contracts.
        </p>

        <p>I am excited to working with you and build out this project.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this error on console

> core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: response.json is not a function
>   core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: this.proposal is not a function
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (proposal-show.component.ts:27)
>       at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
>       at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124)
>       at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
>       at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:69)
>       at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
>       at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
>       at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)

Note: The API is working properly and does not have any issues.
The API server is on rails

Comment: proposalRequest.subscribe(response => (this.proposal = response.json()));
what's the response ?

Comment: You have marked `proposal` as an `@Input`, but actually seem to be getting it from the service; that's likely unrelated to the problem, but is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Mridul I've updated the error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: response.json is not a function

You're using `HttpClient`, so there's no need to call `json` on the response, because it's already called (by Angular HttpClient). Try:

```
proposalRequest.subscribe(response => this.proposal = response);
```

Comment: Works like charm , Thanks <3